# save http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?vars image with php curl, fsockopen or fopen

Tags: php, api, curl, google-street-view

For an application i'me building i would like to use a streetview image from http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=*myaddressvariable*&size=*mysizes*&key=*myapikey*&*restofvars...*

this works fine when getting this image trought a normal browser request.

But i'd really like to save this image using php -> cUrl or fsockopen or fopen.
strange thing is that regardless the php function i use the request times out and i get a 400 error from google.

Is this a permission issue or am i doing something wrong?

So what is the best way to save an image from google streetview using a server side request with php?

Comment: Scraping google pages is against their TOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do. Do whatever you want with it, you may have to edit it. I use cache also.

```
public  function Flat($Coors='', $Zoom=15, $Size='250x200'){
    #   Ok, on doit avoir des coordonnées valides
    $Coors = array_map('trim', explode(',', $Coors));

    $CoorsName = array();
    foreach($Coors as $X){
        if(!is_numeric($X)){
            $Error = 1;
        } else {
            if($X[0] == '-'){
                $CoorsName[] = substr($X, 0, 6);
            } else {
                $CoorsName[] = substr($X, 0, 5);
            }
        }
    }
    $Coors = implode(',', $Coors);
    $CoorsName = implode('_', $CoorsName);

    #   Le zoom doit aussi être valide
    if(!is_numeric($Zoom) OR !is_int($Zoom)){
        $Error = 1;
    }

    #   Maintenant on doit s'assurer de la grandeur
    $Size = array_map('trim', explode('x', $Size));

    foreach($Size as $X){
        if(!is_numeric($X)){
            $Error = 1;
        }
    }
    $Size = implode('x', $Size);

    #   Ok, avant d'aller chercher l'image, on doit vérifier le cache
    $ImageExist = false;

    #   Est-ce que les dossiers existes ?
    $CachePath = '/home/.../cache/maps/flat/';
    $PathLevel = array( $CachePath.$Zoom.'/',
                        $CachePath.$Zoom.'/'.$Size.'/',
                        $CachePath.$Zoom.'/'.$Size.'/'.$CoorsName.'/');

    foreach($PathLevel as $Path){
        if(!file_exists($Path)){
            mkdir($Path, 0777);
        }
    }

    #   Chemin complet de l'image
    $ImagePath = $PathLevel[2].$Coors.'.png';
    $GoogleURL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?';
    $Args = array(  'center'    => $Coors,
                    'zoom'      => $Zoom,
                    'size'      => $Size,
                    'markers'   => 'icon:http://www.domain.com/pin.png|'.$Coors,
                    'sensor'    => 'false');

    $URL_GET = '';
    foreach($Args as $Arg => $Value){
        $URL_GET.= ($URL_GET != '' ? '&' : '') . $Arg.'='.$Value.'&';
    }
    $GoogleURL.= ($URL_GET != '' ? '?'.$URL_GET : '');

    #   On va vérifier si l'image existe maintenant
    if(!file_exists($ImagePath)){
        $Content = file_get_contents($GoogleURL);

        $fHandle = fopen($ImagePath, 'a');
        fwrite($fHandle, $Content);
        fclose($fHandle);

    //  file_put_contents($ImagePath, $Content);
    } else {
        $ImageExist = true;
    }

    #   Header requis
    header('Pragma: public'); // Requis
    header('Expires: 0'); 
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); 
    header('Cache-Control: private', false); // Requis
    header('Content-Type: image/png'); 
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 

    #   On va afficher l'image maintenant
    if($ImageExist === true){
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($ImagePath));
        readfile($ImagePath); 
    } else {
        header('Content-Length: '.strlen($Content));
        echo $Content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the usefull function, i found out that i had to replace all spaces with %20. Since it is an ajax request the 400 message was because of the url beeing malformed.

Comment: My pleasure. At least, you found the problem.